# Android: activity stack not preserved from Home

Tags: android, android-activity

I've tested with a basic POC project with 3 activities A, B, C.

```
<application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name"          
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".MainBActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar">
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".MainCActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar">
        </activity>
    </application>
```

So, from Activity A I can start Activity B (click on button), and from Activity B I can start Activity C.

I just call Activity like that:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), XXXXX.class);
XXXXX.this.startActivity(intent);
```

I don't finish Activities.

So, I have A > B > C.

The current behavior A > B > C > HOME > A 
The expected behavior A > B > C > HOME > C, B, A

I don't understand which configuration I should make.

Ps: when I debug from Android Studio, the behavior expected is correct. If I install this APK, there is this problem.

Thank you very much guys!

Comment: did you write finish(); while going to another activity? If not, then please share your code of going from activity A to activity B, and activity B to activity C

Comment: I've updated my initial post. Thank you very much!